# Customizing App Appearance on Xcode 3?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible to customize the app's appearance using Xcode 3? I'm just waiting for Mountain Lion to download Xcode 4, but I want to customize my App's appearance.

Comment: What are you trying to customize? Your question is vague.

Comment: @JackHumphries the appearance. Say, I want to add an image to the navbar and the tabbar etc.

Comment: You can still edit things the same way in Xcode 3 as you can in Xcode 4. In Xcode 3 though, you have to open Interface Builder as a separate program to edit XIB files. The code and the rest is still the same.

Comment: @JackHumphries I know you add the navbars and stuff with Interface Builder, but how do you add an image to it?

Comment: What OS X version are you using? You don't need Mountain Lion to run Xcode 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you use the interface builder. What are you specifically trying to customize? Your question is incredibly vague. Also, you know you can still download Xcode 4 without mountain lion installed.

Here is a link on how to go about customizing your app's UI:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_quick_start/020-Tutorial_Designing_a_User_Interface_with_Interface_Builder/interface_builder_tutorial.html

EDIT:

You said you wanted to add an image to a Nav bar. Just check the class reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html

Use `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:`